# Break out of Iframe

Tags: php, iframe

I have a Joomla site, the content is loaded in an iframe from another site.
In this iframe I have another iframe (a news ticker), when I click on a link in the news ticker, a page should open in the parent iframe.

When I click on it now, it opens the correct page full screen, and not in the iframe in the joomla site.

(Inception!)

Go check it out:
http://www.rtc-antwerpen.be/Site/content/view/14/47/
Click on 'Hybridevoertuigen' in the scroller

Warning: This site is very old, ugly and slow, I just have to upgrade it.

Thanks

Comment: I've looked at the site, and there's only one iframe. No nested iframe's seem to exist?

Comment: Are you sure your IFrame loads within annother IFrame? for I can see only one IFrame on your site. The one the newsticker is located in. So if you use target="_parent" the browser links correctly to the entire page (since there is no other IFrame wrapping it.

Comment: mmm ok maybe the content on this page is just joomla and no iframe, but I don't think it changes anything

Comment: yes there is only 1 iframe, within that one there is a page whick has a link the should open outside that iframe

Comment: I'll have to go home now, thanks and I'll look back at it tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the a-tag you have to define `target="_parent"`

```
<a href="link.php" target="_parent">
```

This will cause the link to open in the parent frame.

EDIT:

What you seam to be trying to do, is target a div-block outside the IFrame, which is not possible (at least not with some JS running on your main site).

Are the contents you are linking contents, that exist within joomla? Then try to link to their correct URL.

For example, instead of "detail.php?id=435" link to "/Site/content/view/14/435". Then joomla will load the whole site, wrapping the content.

Comment: He has that. This is from his website: <a target="_parent" href="detail.php?id=435">Hybridevoertuigen</a>

Comment: I already tried this, also _self, but go check out my site.
Now the correct page is opening in the entire screen, and not in the parent iframe

Answer (score 1):

Except for `target="_parent"` (which should work if your site is structured like you described) or `target="_self"` (which should work in your site as it actually is structured now), you could also specify the name of a frame in target. That allows you to more specifically point to a target frame, and it is ignored if such a frame does not exist.